# Matching directory paths with a value in python

Tags: python

I have this code where I search for a value (inputCategory), which often is in the end of a path (eg `/blah/blah/<category/blah` or sometimes `/blah/blah/<category>`

```
def category_search(inputDirectory, inputCategory, root):
    categorySearch = os.path.split(os.path.normpath(inputDirectory)) 
    if categorySearch[1] == inputName:
        Logger.info("SEARCH: Files appear to be in their own directory")
        categorySearch2 = os.path.split(os.path.normpath(categorySearch[0]))
        if categorySearch2[1] == twoCategory or categorySearch2[1] == oneCategory:
            if not inputCategory:
            Logger.info("SEARCH: Determined Category to be: %s", categorySearch2[1])
                inputCategory = categorySearch2[1]
        elif not inputCategory:
            Logger.error("SEARCH: Could not identify category from the directory structure.")
            sys.exit(-1)
        else:
            pass

    elif categorySearch[1] == twoCategory or categorySearch[1] == oneCategory:
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(inputDirectory, inputName)):
            inputDirectory = os.path.join(inputDirectory, inputName)
        else:
            Logger.info("SEARCH: The directory passed is the root directory for category %s", categorySearch[1])
            Logger.info("SEARCH: We will try and determine which files to process, individually")
            root = 1
        if not inputCategory:
            Logger.info("SEARCH: Determined Category to be: %s", categorySearch[1])
            inputCategory = categorySearch[1]
    elif not inputCategory:
        Logger.error("SEARCH: Could not identify category from the directory structure")
        sys.exit(-1)
    else:
        Logger.info("SEARCH: The directory passed does not appear to include a category")
        root = 1
    return inputDirectory, inputCategory, root
```

But the thing is the code isn't very dynamic and can be thrown off for example if I get a path like `/blah/blah/<category>/blah/blah`

I'm looking for input on how to optimize this code, catch situations like above and perhaps more?

I'm pretty new at python so be gentle :) Thanks for help!

Comment: What is your goal here, to return the path leading up to the `inputCategory`, starting from `inputDirectory`, or to return everything _after_ the `inputCategory` in the `inputDirectory`?

Comment: The entire functions purpose is to determine if a "category" resides in the path, eg /path/to/something/<category>/something then return true and with the entire path to inputName (which often is /path/to/something/<category>/<inputName>

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this for a path check , but not sure if its what you looking for...
 im Also very green in python!

```
# deconstruct the folder: /a/b/c --> /a/b --> /a --> /
pathHead, pathTail = os.path.split(inputDirectory)  
while pathTail and ( pathTail != inputCategory ): 
    pathHead,pathTail = os.path.split(pathHead)

if not pathTail:
    print 'didnt find category'
else:
    print 'found category: ',pathTail , ' in path: ' , pathHead
```

Edit: fixed elif to else ...